# Java offline functionality progressive web app

Tags: javascript, java, progressive-web-apps, web-development-server

What technology would you recommend to build an offline available web app? My backend should be in Java because I am the most comfortable with Java but I don't know what skills are needed for the offline web app? the offline part is displaying, editing and inserting rows out of a database and being able to print the table in a pdf file. I've read about Service Workers but is there any way to make them work in Java or do I need to get more into JavaScript/TypeScript or something similar?

I was looking for frameworks that allow a complete build in java but my search was not successful

Comment: You have to store data to localstorage and sync it with each request. I didnt do it but only way to offline web to work is browsers memory. Think in a way that each result in http request needs to update localstorage first and each operation needs to be received from localstorage

Comment: You need to cache css or javascript if it is not single page application.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/

Comment: It is pure frontend design not related to java

Comment: Use a mobile-web technology like [https://ionicframework.com/]